Question about hierarchy in Balkan FamilyTree JS
I am absolutely new in Balkan FamilyTree JS.
I have a simple script https://codepen.io/igor-isaev/pen/XWLGVWM where top level the King and the Queen at top level are located. But I want to add another top level wife (with direct connection) for the King e.g. Victoria. And really don't understand how to do that, this doesn't works:
  { id: 3, pids:[1], name: "Queen Victory", title: "The Queen Mother", img: "https://cdn.balkan.app/shared/f2.png", gender: 'female' }

I understand that my question is very simple but after reading some docs I can't solve it by myself.
If I do this way records are the same level but no connection between
    {id: 1, pids: [1], name: "King George VI", title: "01.01.1900 - 01.01.2020", img: "https://cdn.balkan.app/shared/f1.png", gender: 'male' },
    {id: 2, pids: [2], name: "Queen Elizabeth", title: "The Queen Mother", img: "https://cdn.balkan.app/shared/f2.png", gender: 'female' },
   {id: 3, pids: [3], name: "Queen Victory", title: "The Queen Mother", img: "https://cdn.balkan.app/shared/f2.png", gender: 'female' },


actually if you added that object literal as the third item of the list you pass to chart.load() you'll have 3 items on the same level. So it's unclear what's going wrong and what you did actually try. If you slimmed down your demo (possibly removing comments) and shared it here, it would be easier to come to a better answer

by the way here: https://balkan.app/FamilyTreeJS/Docs/GettingStarted you can see how to model the relationships between nodes.. just acting on pids: are the partner ids, mid: mother id, fid: father id.

I've tried to post code from codepen here but it doesn't work really don't know why. Thank you a lot for options explanation - i've missed it in documentation.

the reason why it doesn't work here in a live snippet it's because FamilyTreeJS uses the localstorage that's not allowed in a sandboxed environment having some constraints by condtiions set. Anyway you should focus on the pids property that being plural accepts a list of partners. Each node should be connected to its siblings.. so try using [2,3] on the first one; [1,3] on the second one; and [1,2] on the third one. Maybe the plurality could be used only for second one (the one in the middle) and the left and right one just having the connection toward their direct sibling

You need to read the documentation on how the FamilyTree JS works, starting from  here: https://balkan.app/FamilyTreeJS/Docs/GettingStarted
pids are the partners of that id. You cannot be a partner of yourself.
Here is how you should add Victoria Queen:
https://code.balkan.app/familytree-js/queen-victoria#JS

I understand how to add one wife to one husband but don't understand how to add 2 wives to 1 husband.

Wives should be an array. I hope you will understand it from the docs.
